# PDF.js can't show PDF from externalFilesDir at Android 11

Tags: android, pdf.js, android-storage

I am using PDF.js to show PDF files inside my Android App. Up to Android 10 it worked fine, but starting with "targetSdkVersion 30" it doesn't work anymore.

If I want to open and show a PDF file, PDF.js shows

`Missing PDF "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<App-ID>/files/file.pdf`

The path ist definitely correct, I checked it and generated it with `getExternalFilesDir(null).absolutePath`

The whole URL to load is
`file:///android_asset/web/viewer.html?file=/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<app-ID>/files/file.pdf`

Using "targetSdkVersion 29" and changing nothing else, all works fine, so it seems "targetSdkVersion 30" causes somehow the problem.

Comment: Who created that pdf file? Your app? Or how did it land there? Inside your Android app? You use a WebView?

Comment: I use webview to open the URL. My app is downloading the PDF. The download works fine and it's also possible to open the PDF with an intent (e.g. to use Adobe PDF reader). So the problem is either pdf.js itself or webview. Because I only use the app data dir, storage permissions shouldn't be a problem, right?

Answer (score 8):

The solution was pretty simple (shame on me):

Up to API 29 I only used:

```
webView.settings.allowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true
```

Since API 30 I have to use:

```
webView.settings.allowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true
webView.settings.allowFileAccess = true
```

Comment: but still blank page appeared on my side.
do you have  any other clues @Tefracky?

Comment: No, I don't. I have two apps and both work fine. Maybe you can provide a little bit more detail or code and so on.